# Log4j2 create new log file if not exist

Tags: java, file, logging, log4j, log4j2

I am using `RollingRandomAccessFile` appende for log4j logging and everything is working fine ,

```
    <RollingRandomAccessFile name="xxx.FLT" fileName="${sys:xxx.log.path}FLT.log" filePattern="${sys:xxx.log.path}FLT.log.%i" append="true" immediateFlush="true" bufferSize="262144">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} [%t] %level{WARN=WARNING, DEBUG=FINE, ERROR=SEVERE} %logger{36} - %convInfo %msg%n"/>
        <Policies>
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="100MB"/>
        </Policies>
        <DefaultRolloverStrategy fileIndex="max" min="1" max="5" compressionLevel="3"/>
    </RollingRandomAccessFile>
```

At the application startup all the log files are created. I have an another process that remove log file from the disc if they are not getting update after some time.

if this process removed a log file, it will not create again at a new log event.

**I want to create new log file if not exist in the given location at the time of new log event has been occurred**

I know when the application restart missing files will be created again , but i want to create log file at the time of a log event occurred.

**I am preferred to have a configuration level change other than a code level change.**

Answer (score -1):

All you need to do is to make sure your removal of log files is only handled by log4j. This way you will never loose the current log file.

Comment: Yes i think it is the better way , but that process cannot be stop here...